# Is there any centralized way to limit the exposure of api's to swagger ui in regarding openAPI?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have just migrated to spring-doc openAPI from springfox, right now it's exposing all our api's  present in my spring-boot projects for documentation. Is there any centralized way to govern that thing because using @Hidden annotation will not be feasible in our case for that we have to amend our all controllers.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: this should fit your needs.... https://dev.to/s2agrahari/grouping-apis-in-swagger-55kk

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

`springdoc.paths-to-exclude` property with List of Strings.The list of paths to exclude (comma separated)

Or `springdoc.packages-to-exclude` property with List of Strings.The list of packages to exclude (comma separated).

Or you can load groups dynamically using spring-boot configuration files.
Note that, for this usage, you don’t have to declare the GroupedOpenApi Bean.
You need to declare the following properties, under the prefix springdoc.group-configs.

```
springdoc.group-configs[0].group=users
springdoc.group-configs[0].paths-to-match=/user/**
springdoc.group-configs[0].packages-to-scan=test.org.springdoc.api
```